# laravel 9 not loading css & js, but does load images

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, tailwind-css, vite, laravel-9

I have recently uploaded my Laravel project to a host. the problem is my images in the `public/images` folder are loaded correctly, but my js and css files in `public/build/assets` folder are not found. I'm really confused, the line below

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

produces these lines in the view:

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://sample.com/build/assets/app-174f79b2.css">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="https://sample.com/build/assets/app-02908d50.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sample.com/build/assets/app-174f79b2.css">
<script type="module" src="https://sample.com/build/assets/app-02908d50.js"></script>
```

and they cannot be found. But when I copy links to the browser and add `public` before `build`, they are there. I think it is something wrong with the `.htaccess` file, but my index.php in the public folder doesn't have this problem and it works. My images folder under the public folder also work fine and my images are loaded correctly.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Something that is more strange to me is that my `.svg` files in the `public/images` folder has also loading problem. But `.webp` files are okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#running-vite)

> There are two ways you can run Vite. You may run the development server via the `dev` command, which is useful while developing locally. The development server will automatically detect changes to your files and instantly reflect them in any open browser windows.
>
> Or, running the build command will version and bundle your application's assets and get them ready for you to deploy to production

### So...

Laravel Vite doesn't build and publish assets to your public folder in development mode! It opens another port and serve them it self.

```
npm run dev
```

If you want to publish your assets you should run for production:

```
npm run build
```

### Accessing laravel when document root is not public

You should set your `Documentroot` as your `public` directory.

But if you don't want to do that in `.htaccess` in your laravel root which is your document root write this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have run `npm run build` and my versioned files are present. They're just not accessible by `/build/assets/fu.bar`, but accessible by `/public/build/assets/fu.bar`

Comment: it produced this line: `No input file specified.`

Comment: Buddy your document root is not public folder! If you do that everything will work easily.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file should be in `public` folder

Comment: I changed the document root to public and everything seems fine. thanks for your help. But is it a safe thing to do?

Comment: It is exactly what should be done. Don't worry.